# Not getting correct client public IP with this.connection.clientAddress

Tags: meteor

Using `this.connection.clientAddress` server side doesn't provide me with the correct user IP address in Meteor. Supposedly, that's Meteor's built in standard for retrieving a user's IP server side, but all I'm getting is the standard 172.xx.xxx IP's, which don't correspond to my actual IP.

I have tried 3rd party APIs and several node modules, and they all work like they should. However, the issue with `this.connection.clientAddress` still persists.

```
// Client
Meteor.call("getIP", funciton(error, result){
console.log(result);
});

// Server
getIP: function(){
return this.connection.clientAddress;
}
```

Could this be due to an nginx proxy problem on my development server? Any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

Your server is likely not to have a public IP address, which is why it only provides you with the internal ip 172.xx.xxx.xxx

The firewall / load balancer does the forwarding of packets from the published ip address. The exact arrangement will depend on who is hosting the server.

You will need to either pass the public ip address as an environment variable to Meteor, hardcode it (not recommended) or put it in a database collection.

**Update:** Here is a solution using environment variables saved into a Mongo collection:

Assuming your server setup allows you to specify environment variables, either in a shell script or in the config file. My example uses Nginx/Passenger.

```
# Tell the app where MongoDB is
passenger_env_var MONGO_URL mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject;
# Tell the app what its other settings are
passenger_env_var ROOT_URL https://dev.myproject.online;

passenger_env_var IMAGE_DIR /var/www/imgserver/public;
```

In the server, a meteor method reads the environment variables and inserts them into a collection:

```
// Get a list of environment vars and put them in the Environs collection
// - client code will pick these up and handle them.
  getEnvirons: function() {
    Environs.remove({});    // Force them to be re-read every server startup
    var toGet = ["ROOT_URL", "IMAGE_DIR"]; // Edit this as you please
    _.each(toGet, function(e){
      var val = process.env[e];
      Environs.insert({name: e, value: val});
    });
  },
```

Call the above from a Meteor startup block in the server.

All that remains to be done is to publish the Environs collection and subscribe to it. (I am assuming you know how to do that). The loading of the environment variable data will be asynchronous of course, so allow for that in your code

Comment: Sure, if it works on your project, please share how to get this to work. I would appreciate it.

Comment: I'm using Digital Ocean's Ubuntu setup via regular Mup. Which file do I have to place the environmental variables in? I have them set in the `Meteor.isServer` inside my app at the moment. That's an awfully long process + database insertions to get the user's IP.

Comment: Actually I think I gave you a bad steer, I thought you were wanting the server ip

Comment: It's a different challenge. Basically the firewall should pass through the user's ip address in the HTML headers. It may not be doing this. Check the firewall setup (or ask Digital Ocean) on how to tackle it